# A function in JS with parameter passing

Tags: javascript

It's the test task on the job.

A farmer has rabbits. Each rabbit is its weight. When the time comes, he kills them function `cut(rabbit)`.
You must write a function of cut so that it had the appearance of
`cut(rabbit1)(rabbit2)...(rabbitN)` and deduced the total mass and the number of rabbits.

For example:

```
var rabbit1 = {weight: 5},
    rabbit2 = {weight: 4};

console.log(cut(rabbit1)(rabbit2));
```

In the console we will see "9 kg of rabbits or 2 pieces".

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sjao7ut8/

How I can write function `cut()`?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I don't know how I can pass parameters in function like this.

Comment: If you need more than one parameter (rabbit1, ...., rabbitn), you just pass all the rabbits you want. Javascript functions don't care

Comment: why dont you use array rabbits instead of rabbit1, rabbit2, and so on ? and also show us what you've done so far.

Comment: You need to research function currying.  I wouldn't be surprised if you need to have an empty set of parentheses at the end too, ie `console.log(cut(rabbit1)(rabbit2)());`

Comment: If I understand the words "test task on the job" correctly, you have applied for a job which obviously wants you to have a certain level of javascript skills. And then you say you "don't know how you can pass parameters in function like this"?

Comment: @devnull69 It's not my task, but I want to know the solution.

Comment: shouldnt it be 'kill' rabbit rather than 'cut' rabbit. as 'cut' is a specific implementation of kill. would be more generic. also, not everything that gets cut dies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use chaining, a fluent interface, which returns the function you called until the environment requires a primitive value.

```js
function cut(rabbit) {
    var weight = 0,
        count = 0,
        fn = function (o) {
            weight += o.weight;
            count++;
            return fn;
        };

    fn.toString = function () {
        return weight + ' kg of rabbits or ' + count + ' piece' + (count > 1 ? 's' : '');
    }

    return fn(rabbit);
}

var rabbit1 = { weight: 5 },
    rabbit2 = { weight: 4 };
    
console.log(cut(rabbit1)(rabbit2));
```

Comment: In the chrome dev console this prints and extra `function` before the output. Can anything be done about that?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen, you can prepend an empty string, like `console.log('' + cut(rabbit1)(rabbit2));`

Comment: @JustusRomijn, yes, because the function is retuned

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do here is to use *recursive* call, which returns a *function* and uses `arguments.callee`

something like this should do the job:

```
function cut(firstRabbit) {
    var mass = firstRabbit.weight;
    return function(nextRabbit) {
        if (typeof nextRabbit !== 'undefined') {
            mass += nextRabbit.weight;
            return arguments.callee;
        } else {
            return mass;
        }
    };
}
```

Example usage (remember to add **()** at the end):

```
var rabbit1 = {weight: 5},
rabbit2 = {weight: 4};

console.log(cut(rabbit1)(rabbit2)());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
var farmer = { 
    cut: function(rabits) { 
    var cutWeight = 10;
    var totalCuts = 0;
    var totalWeight = 0;
    var count = rabits.length;

    for(var i=0; i < count; i++) {
        var rabit = rabits[i];

      if(rabit.weight >= cutWeight) {
        totalWeight += rabit.weight;
        if(totalCuts === 0) {
            totalCuts = 1;
        }
        else {
            totalCuts += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(totalWeight + "Kg of Rabits and " + totalCuts + "cuts.")
  }
};

farmer.cut([{weight: 11}, {weight: 5}, {weight: 13}]); // Call the function
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
 return Function.prototype.rabbitsWeight + "кг кроликов или " + Function.prototype.rabbitsCount + " штук";
}; 

Function.prototype.rabbitsWeight = 0;
Function.prototype.rabbitsCount = 0;

window.rabbitsCut = eval("new Function('rabbit', 'Function.prototype.rabbitsWeight += rabbit.weight; ++Function.prototype.rabbitsCount; return eval(window.rabbitsCut);');");

var cut = window.rabbitsCut;

console.log(cut({weight: 5})({weight: 4}));
```